# Material preview/eevee 3d view glitches and no compatible GPU found

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, gpu, hardware, compatibility

Blender recently started crashing when trying to use cycles with my gpu, and then when I'm in EEVEE or material preview the 3d view goes weird colours (mainly grey) and duplicates visuals around.

I updated my gpu and blender and now it lets me use cycles with my gpu but it still says "No compatible gpu found for path tracing" in preferences despite that, and I still have the 3d view glitchyness. Also my gpu still runs games fine.

Here are pictures of what my 3d view looks like, and what happens when I move my mouse around and scroll in and out in eevee with this cube and glowy circle.

[image: House in eevee]

[image: what happens when I move my mouse around and scroll in and out in eevee]

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have? As always in these cases, make sure your graphics drivers are up to date, and check here to make sure your GPU is supported - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/.

Comment: @Christopher I have the RX 480, and they're up to date now but the problem stayed, and yeah it looks like it's supported, it had been working fine up until recently.

Comment: The only thing I can think is to make sure you're using OpenCL and not CUDA, but other than that, I'm not sure. I've seen a lot of the same complaints here recently concerning the RX 580 as well.

Comment: I guess it's your graphics card: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203615/how-to-fix-material-and-render-previews#comment342453_203615

Comment: @brockmann Ye that looks like a very similar problem to mine, although the problem didn't start after any changes to my gpu drivers, at least not to my knowledge